# Is there a way to customize a flowbite Datepicker in React

Tags: reactjs, flowbite

I'm using the `<Datepicker/>` component but unable to customize it, if I add a `className` directly to the component, which is what `flowbite` recommends for component customization, I only end up customizing the input field, not the actual popup datepicker.

Comment: https://www.flowbite-react.com/docs/components/datepicker#theme